# ldapsearch - how to display “lastLogonTimestamp” & convert windows lastlogontimestamp to date in bash

Tags: bash, active-directory, bash-scripting, ldap

I want to search Active Directory for inactive users that have no login for x days/months. I've got such a ldapsearch query:

```
ldapsearch -h domain.test -p 389 -D "cn=login,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=test" -w "passwd" -s sub -b "ou=Test,dc=domain,dc=test" "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
```

It gives me the list of all inactive users in domain.test with all attributes.

I would like to add a filter for searching users that have no login for x days/months, and it would be great if the result was the list of sAMAccountNames (inactive user and lastLogonTimestamp >e.g. 3months).
I'm aware that LastLogonTimestamp is not the real time of last user logon, but in this case it's not so important.

EDIT: now I only need to know if there is a way to show attribute like "lastLogonTimestamp" in the output of above ldapsearch query?

**ANSWER**: Attribute lastLogonTimestamp was not set for each object in the output of above ldapsearch query. I haven't noticed that. So grep displayed it:

```
ldapsearch -h domain.test -p 389 -D "cn=login,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=test" -w "passwd" -s sub -b "ou=Test,dc=domain,dc=test" "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountCont‌​rol:1.2.840.113556.1‌​.4.803:=2))" | grep -i lastlogontimestamp
```

EDIT: To convert windows lastLogonTimestamp to date I've used:

```
while read -r line;
    do
    let "ts = ($line / 10000000) - 11644473600" && echo $ts >> linux_timestamp;
    date -d @$ts +'%Y%m%d' >> linux_date;
    done < users_lastlogontimestamp
```

Any advice very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your filter to add another condition, so that ldap server returns only entries with lastLogonTimestamp>=**timestamp**.
To retrieve only specific attributes instead of the whole entry, specify the attributes to be returned by the server.

For example:-

```
ldapsearch -h domain.test -p 389 -D "cn=login,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=test" -w "passwd" -s sub -b "ou=Test,dc=domain,dc=test" "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(lastlogontimestamp>=131550784796762354))" samAccountName lastlogontimestamp
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the problem is that lastLogonTimestamp values are not comparable, thus I cannot use lastLogonTimestamp<=timestamp_value to get list of users that lastlogon was eg. before 01/06/2017. I need to convert lastLogonTimestamp to date, then use it in ldapsearch query filter.

Comment: Quick search lists many examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091719/converting-lastlogon-to-datetime-format , Convert your date the lastlogontimestamp and use ldapsearch with the value.

Comment: That's right, but what I need is conversion form windows lastLogonTimestamp to date in linux (bash script). I would like to have all operations in one place (without using PowerShell as an additional tool for example).

Comment: per AD docs, the lastlogintimestamp is the time in ns since 1601 and it can be easily converted, there are many examples available online. for eg: http://meinit.nl/convert-active-directory-lastlogon-time-to-unix-readable-time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer Najmuddin.

I though that it will be ok to compare lastlogontimestamps - it isn't because lastlogontimestamp values are not comparable. The only was is to convert to date format first, and then compare to get users that lastlogon was eg. before 01/06/2017. And here's the question: how to convert windows lastlogontimestamp to date in bash?

Please let me know if it's the correct way to do it.